# I dont see bluetooth in rfkill list in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, rfkill

I am trying to start Bluetooth service in Ubuntu 20.04.

I have installed Bluetooth manager and it shows "bluez daemon is not not running, blueman manager cannot continue, probably means there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluez daemon was not started"

I ran command in terminal and got rfkill list and there was no bluetooth listed only wireless Lan.

What do I do?

```
LAPTOP HP MODEL: 15da1058TU
Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
```

I can not find any information about Bluetooth. I think it doesn't have Bluetooth.

I ran this command in the terminal.

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

output:

```
audit: type=1107 audit(1629435095.152:91): 
pid=1075 uid=103 auid=4294967295 
ses=4294967295 
subj=unconfined 
msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  
bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" 
member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=11367
label="snap.brave.brave
```

Then I ran `sudo lshaw -C network` .

output:

```
network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: ec:5c:68:69:b5:6b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8723de driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.57 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff
```

Comment: What is your laptop model? Does your Bluetooth chipset appear in `lsusb`, `lspci` or `lshw`? If so, can you update the post with your Bluetooth chipset? Otherwise, can you tel us your Wi-Fi chipset?

Comment: update is done,

Comment: Your Bluetooth is provided by the RTL8723DE combo wireless adapter shown in the `lshw` output. Support was added to the kernel mainline for this adapter, so it should be working. Have you tried Ubuntu 21.04, which has a newer kernel version?

Comment: No. I am using linux for first time with UBUNTU 20.04. is there any way to get bluetooth started?

Comment: Can you try booting 21.04 to see if it does resolve your issue?